# Update custom field with Cron Job in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, cron, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to setup a cron job for a custom post type (Job Listings), that contains two ACF custom fields.

1. Datepicker – User can choose closing date of the job ( ‘job_listing_closing_date’ )
2. Radio field – Open & Closed choices. ( ‘job_listing_status’ )

I need the radio field to change from ‘Open’ to ‘Closed’ in the backend post edit screen if the *job_listing_closing_date* has passed. Here is my code at the moment which is located within ‘/wp-content/themes/themename/assets/functions/cpt-job-listings.php file.

I’ve added the below to code to the website but nothing happens.
Maybe the query is wrong or the ACF fields aren’t available in the file I have coded in?

```
// Create a cron job in order to check the custom field of 'job_listing_closing_date' against today's date. If the date has passed, set the job status to 'closed' and display different content on front-end.

// Scheduled Action Hook
function check_job_end_date( ) {

  // WP_Query arguments
    $listings = array (
        'post_type'              => 'job_listings',
        'posts_per_page'         => -1,
        'meta_key'               => 'job_listing_closing_date',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key'     => 'job_listing_closing_date',    
            'value'   => date( 'Ymd' ),
            'compare' => '<',   
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
        )
    );

  global $post;
  if ($listings->have_posts()) {
    while ($listings->have_post()) {
      $listings->the_post();
      update_field('job_listing_job_status', 'Closed');
      //update_post_meta($post->ID, 'job_listing_job_status', 'Closed');
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
}

// Schedule Cron Job Event
function job_listing_cron_job() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'check_job_end_date' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( date( 'Ymd' ), 'daily', 'check_job_end_date' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up rewriting most of the code and this is what worked:

```
// Create a cron job in order to check the custom field of 'job_listing_closing_date' against today's date. If the date has passed, set the job status to 'closed' and display different content on front-end.

// Scheduled Action Hook
function check_job_end_date( ) {

  global $post;

  $args = array( 
    'post_type'       => 'job_listings',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  );

  $listings = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($listings as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

  $today = date( 'Ymd' );
  $expire = get_field( 'job_listing_closing_date', false, false );
    $status = get_field( 'job_listing_job_status' );
        if ( $expire < $today ) :
            $status = 'Closed';
            update_field( 'job_listing_job_status', $status );
        endif;  
    endforeach;

}

// Schedule Cron Job Event

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'job_listing_cron_job' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( date( 'Ymd' ), 'daily', 'job_listing_cron_job' );
}
add_action( 'job_listing_cron_job', 'check_job_end_date' );
```

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but the first parameter in `wp_schedule_event` accepts a timestamp, not a date in format `Ymd` as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $listings = array (
    'post_type'              => 'job_listings',
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'meta_key'               => 'job_listing_closing_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => 'job_listing_closing_date',    
        'value'   => date( 'Ymd' ),
        'compare' => '<',   
        'type'    => 'DATE',
    )
);
```

And sure is the correct date format `date( 'Ymd' )`

Comment: Tested with DATE also and checked that the date formats match. I also created a custom page template and run this WP_Query to see if it echo'd out the correct details, which it does.